# Product that saves email attachments to disk

Tags: c#, exchange-server

I deal with vendors all the time who seem to only have the capability to transmit files via email with an attachment.

I am looking for a solution that can subscribe to an email account, then turn around and publish those attachments to a network share where another process could pick them up.  The only product I know of that will do this in a general fashion is BizTalk.  However, I can't justify spending the $10K or $40K on a license for a product that I am only going to use 1% of so I am looking for some options.  [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300813.aspx) describes almost exactly what I would need.

What I need

- A solution that can run as a service and not a VBA script.
- Commercial License (source code inclusion would be great)
- Cheaper than BizTalk
- Something that doesn't need a dedicated server
- Easily able to add new scenarios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout [Email2DB](http://www.email2db.com/)

- runs as service
- nice userinterface
- it can monitore different emailbox
- it supports rules (you decide which mails you want to process
- it supports different backends as a store (SQL Databases, FileSystem, ...)
- it is scritable: if it does not support wht you are doing, you can write a script for that
- it is pretty cheap, enterprise version less than 1000€
- and ...

I used it for our last customer. It does get the job done. And it is easy to configure it. They have a (full) evaluation license, so you can try it out for 30 days or so.

Comment: This looks really promising, checking it out now.